# Array copying crashes app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
NSArray *mruSearchItems;
NSMutableArray *mruItems;

self.mruItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"searches"]];

. 
.
 At this point mruItems becomes empty.
.
.
self.mruSearchItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.mruItems];
```

The last line causes a crash.

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Why is that ?

Comment: Have you somehow dealloced mruItems?  What is your code between the two points you have already shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use dot notation syntax (`self.mruSearchItems`) you need to make `mruSearchItems` a property.

Like this right under your @implementation line of your .m file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *mruSearchItems;
```

If you already have a property (and have just not shown it here) make sure that it is `strong` (not `weak`) otherwise your arrays will be released.

Comment: Yes I do. Failed to mention that. I am programming for iOS 4, so it is a monatomic,retain.

Comment: Now I noticed there was [self.mruSearchItems release]; in the code between. But when the code is released, can I not simply realloc ?

Comment: First off, it's the memory is released not the code.  Second, yes, you can always reallocate more memory for your array; however, as you have the code above, you don't do so. Instead, you try to use `self.mruItems` to allocate your new array even though `self.mruItems` no longer points to valid memory

Comment: I call removeObject on mruItems until it gets empty, But I think it still IS an array, isn't that the case ? So it's only the Array gets empty, not the NSArray object.

Comment: @Ted Don't call release on an object and then expect to use it later.  That is an unbreakable rule.  Your pointer will become invalid if it is deallocated (which in this case it obviously is).